# Brute force attack permutations

Tags: security, math, passwords, password-protection

Assuming an alphanumeric password of 8 characters the amount of permutations by my understanding would be.

26 lowercase
26 uppercase
10 digits

So if you were to do a brute force attack on this password the amount of tries on average would be (62 ^ 8) / 2

> However assuming you knew that the
>   password was at least 4 digits long
>   and therefore excluded any attempts on
>   the first 4 digits would the answer to
>   the remaining permutations not be ((62
>   ^ 8) – (62 ^ 4)) / 2 ?

Am I missing something here or is that the correct answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are missing something. No, that's not the correct answer :-)

Your original calculation is for a password that is *exactly* eight characters long, not one that is eight or less.

For a password which can be between four and eight characters, there's actually *more* search space than in your original calculation (not because less search space equates to more time taken, but because the original calculation was wrong).

For a password of one to eight characters, the search space is actually:

```
(62 ^ 1) + (62 ^ 2) + (62 ^ 3) + (62 ^ 4) +
(62 ^ 5) + (62 ^ 6) + (62 ^ 7) + (62 ^ 8)
```

and then you can divide that by two for the average number of checks (I won't since we're really only talking about ratios here).

Then, if you have the extra information that the password is at least four characters long, you can discount the first three terms to get:

```
                                 (62 ^ 4) +
(62 ^ 5) + (62 ^ 6) + (62 ^ 7) + (62 ^ 8)
```

Comment: Please explain? How does the second example produce a larger search space?

Comment: It produces a larger search space than your original incorrect calculation (62^8), _not_ larger than the correct calculation (the first one I showed) - clarified in the answer.

Comment: Ok sorry got ya. But to be clear if you do have more information specifically that the password MUST BE greater then 4 chars your search space decreases, correct? PS: Thanks for your input

Comment: @Maxim, as my 7yo son would say: correctimundo :-) Your search space decreases if you have information that limits the number of passwords somehow.

Comment: To which Pax wisely said nothing :-) No, he's only just wrapping his noggin around multiplication, powers are beyond him at the moment but with a alpha-geek dad and a high-end corporate forensic accountant mum, I hope he's well set up :-)

Answer (score 0):

For a password of at most 8 characters, there are `62^8 + 62^7 + 62^6 + 62^5 + 62^4 + 62^3 + 62^2 + 62` different passwords. If you know, however, that the password will be no less than 4 characters long, you may remove the last 3 terms, and get something like `62^8 + 62^7 + 62^6 + 62^5 + 62^4` different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the right calculation for the number of combinations possible for your password will be:

```
(62^4) + (62^5) + (62^6) + (62^7) + (62^8)
```